grep command doesn't work for iwconfig
Show wireless network interface:
$ sudo iwconfig | grep wlp4s0 
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

nekoray-tun  no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Redmi_A6F0"  

Why is the result not just one line? Expected result:
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Redmi_A6F0"  


Because only one line contains “wlp4s0”? Please explain in greater detail what you want to accomplish and what you tried. Please separate expected output from actual output.

@DanielB He has shown what he tried and what he is expecting. I don't see how it can be any more clear other than oversimplifying it for the sake of it. If only one line contains wlp4s0, he wants to know why the output of his command doesn't contain only that line and instead contains every line.

On the contrary. The question very much is unclear. And indeed, while it is great that your answer satisfied the author, it does not properly explain what is happening at all: Lines with “no wireless extensions” are printed on stderr, which is why they aren’t filtered by grep.

@DanielB I don't see where it isn't clear. The person asking the question wanted a certain output and wasn't getting it. I have added what you stated to my answer as that does do a better job of explaining it but with that being said, the person seemed more interested in getting the desired output in the question.

You shouldn't use grep for that. Just run sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 for information about that specific interface
Back to your question, the reason for what you saw is because iwconfig writes to both stdout and stderr. You can easily see that by disabling one of the streams
$ sudo iwconfig 2>/dev/null     # Prints only stdout
wlo2      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

$ sudo iwconfig 1>/dev/null     # Prints only stderr
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp69s0   no wireless extensions.
...

That's why these commands from Nasir Riley's answer work, because stderr is redirected into stdout so that grep/sed/awk can read on that stream
iwconfig 2>&1 | grep wlp4s0
iwconfig 2>&1 | sed -n '/wlp4s0/p'
iwconfig 2>&1 | awk '/wlp40/ {print}'

echo $(iwconfig 2>&1) > file is completely wrong, because without double quotes the shell always does word splitting, which removes all the newline characters. That means the output of iwconfig is entirely concatenated and separated by spaces is also wrong, because the above commands already confirms that iwconfig output contains multiple lines
echo "$(iwconfig 2>&1)" > file will work, but it'll fall into the useless use of echo, similar to the useless use of cat. Just use sudo iwconfig >file 2>&1 or sudo iwconfig &>file

There is no need to use echo anjd/or append the output to a file to get the desired output in the question. That is only in my answer to show what is happening as a result of the standard output and standard error being concatenated and that using 2>&1 will send both to stdout. The commands that I gave that actually give the desired output don't include echo and just send everything to stdout so that grep , sed, and `awk' can operate on it.
